# How to fix flexbox issue with IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

We are using Flexbox to create a grid system and found that the elements inside the `<div class="flex-row">` works fine in all browsers except IE 11.

How can we fix the elements so that text makes the box expand normally?

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-col {
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .flex-col {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 24px);
  }
}

@media (max-width:460px) {
  .flex-col {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
<div class="flex-col">Assertively negotiate interoperable portals without cross functional process improvements. Dramatically incentivize tactical best practices with.</div>
<div class="flex-col">Seamlessly grow competitive.</div>
<div class="flex-col">Distinctively optimize user-centric mindshare vis-a-vis plug-and-play infomediaries. Seamlessly optimize impactful solutions and enabled infrastructures.</div>
<div class="flex-col">Dynamically extend flexible catalysts for change via pandemic supply chains. Efficiently.</div>
</div>
```

Current behavior with IE:

[image: IE issue]

Desired results

[image: desired output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing the properties of flex-items with flex-containers.. double check that.

Anyway, your code is not working because of one of the many, many bugs with flexbox and IE. It seems align-items: center; on your flex-columns are the blame. Just removing it makes it work.

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-col {
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="flex-col">Assertively negotiate interoperable portals without cross functional process improvements. Dramatically incentivize tactical best practices with.</div>
  <div class="flex-col">Seamlessly grow competitive.</div>
  <div class="flex-col">Distinctively optimize user-centric mindshare vis-a-vis plug-and-play infomediaries. Seamlessly optimize impactful solutions and enabled infrastructures.</div>
  <div class="flex-col">Dynamically extend flexible catalysts for change via pandemic supply chains. Efficiently.</div>
</div>
```

(I've removed the media queries for SO snippet purposes only)

Do you really need to have your flex-columns as column directioned flex-containers? and if so, do you really need them to be align-items:center?

Comment: @FacundoCarrodini The align-items center was used to center align the items within their respective columns regardless of height

Comment: after removing the align-items it does resolve the issue and remains in the center, thanks

Comment: @drupi17 align-items: stretch (default) on your .flex-row + justify-content:center on your .flex-colum is taking care of that for you ;)